# Precise Timer Queues in C++

Tags: c++, timer, cross-platform

I'm developing an application that needs to send out messages at specific times (it's to do with multimedia so the timing precision is important), so effectively I need a mechanism to call a callback function in a specified number of milliseconds.

I need to support both Windows and Mac OS X. I've looked into Timer Queues on Windows which looks like what I need, but I have read that the timing precision is just not precise enough for multimedia based applications (my application is sensing MIDI messages to a driver at specific times). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet on Windows is to use [Multimedia Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). On OS X, the simplest function to use would be [`nanosleep`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/nanosleep.2.html), but you can go a long way with [kqueue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue). I don't think there will be any problems if you are talking milliseconds precision (a millisecond is a very, very long time). The only thing you will possibly need to do is to make sure OS runs your process as "real-time".

Comment: Yeh I basically wanted to avoid creating my own threads and having to put them to sleep

Answer (score 0):

Any *sleep* function is 'a least' with all OS that I know of.

If theat OS has a lot of tasks it is up to the scheduler for those tasks.

In space they have dedicate hardware that does simple functions from a queue - that is the best you can get - and they are not croweded